# Automating a Cloud Firestore export in python3

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I want to set up an automated backup service of my Cloud Firestore database with a microservice built on flask, the command I need to use:

```
gcloud beta firestore export gs://[BUCKET_NAME]
```

Thats the command I'd like to run via my App Engine microservice

```
@app.route('/backup', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def backup():

    subprocess.call('gcloud beta firestore export gs://bucket-name --async', shell=True)

    return f"Backup process started successfully, you can close this window. {datetime.now(timezone.utc)}"
```

But it doesn't look like anything is happening, I'm assuming thats because my App Engine instance doesn't have CloudSDK.

Is this something I could do in Cloud Function instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an example app that you can call with the Google App Engine Cron Service. It's based on the [node.js example in the docs](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/solutions/schedule-export):

**app.yaml**

```
runtime: python37

handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: auto
```

If you already have a default service deployed, add `target: cloud-firestore-admin` to create a new service.

**requirements.txt**

```
Flask
google-api-python-client
```

The [google-api-python-client](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client) simplifies access to the Cloud Firestore REST API.

**main.py**

```
import datetime
import os
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__) 

@app.route('/cloud-firestore-export')
def export():
    # Deny if not from the GAE Cron Service
    assert request.headers['X-Appengine-Cron']
    # Deny if outputUriPrefix not set correctly
    outputUriPrefix = request.args.get('outputUriPrefix')
    assert outputUriPrefix and outputUriPrefix.startswith('gs://')
    # Use a timestamp in export file name
    timestamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d-%H%M%S')
    if not outputUriPrefix.endswith('/'):
      # Add a trailing slash if missing
      outputUriPrefix += '/' + timestamp
    else:
      outputUriPrefix += timestamp
    if 'collections' in request.args:
      collections = request.args.get('collections').split(",")
    else:
      collections = None

    body = {
        'collectionIds': collections,
        'outputUriPrefix': outputUriPrefix,
    }
    # Build REST API request for 
    # https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.databases/exportDocuments
    project_id = os.environ.get('GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT')
    database_name = 'projects/{}/databases/(default)'.format(project_id)
    service = build('firestore', 'v1')
    service.projects().databases().exportDocuments(name=database_name, body=body).execute()
    return 'Operation started' 


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # This is used when running locally only. When deploying to Google App
    # Engine, a webserver process such as Gunicorn will serve the app. This
    # can be configured by adding an `entrypoint` to app.yaml.
    # Flask's development server will automatically serve static files in
    # the "static" directory. See:
    # http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/quickstart/#static-files. Once deployed,
    # App Engine itself will serve those files as configured in app.yaml.
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080, debug=True)
```

**cron.yaml**

```
cron:
- description: "Daily Cloud Firestore Export"
  url: /cloud-firestore-export?outputUriPrefix=gs://BUCKET_NAME&collections=COLLECTIONS_LIST
  schedule: every 24 hours
```

If you deployed to a non-default service in app.yaml, add it here, too: `target: cloud-firestore-admin`.

***Access permissions for App Engine Service account***

Once deployed, the app uses the GAE service account to authorize export requests. Make sure your GAE service account has permissions for Cloud Firestore and for your Storage bucket, see:

https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/solutions/schedule-export#configure_access_permissions

Comment: It's exactly that: use discovery API ! Thanks @juan-lara, you save my time !

Comment: awesome thank you for the reply! if I don't specify any collections will it default to all or will the `None` indicate to not export anything?

Comment: Yes, it will default to exporting everything. You can verify with `gcloud beta firestore operations list` which will show how many bytes were exported. Also note that if you export everything you will need to import everything. You can't import specific collection from a database-wide export.

Answer (score 1):

You can't perform system calls in sandboxed environment (appengine, functions). Moreover you don't know what is installed on the platform, and it's dangerous/not consistent.

You can try with cloud run, or app engine flex. But it's not a real best practice. The best way is to use Python library to perform the same operation programmatically. In any case, the underlayer result will be the same: an API call.

Comment: Good answer. One additional point. `gcloud` is not an executable that can be directly run by a system call. `gcloud` is a Shell Script that is run from a shell command prompt such as `bash`. As a shell script, `gcloud` requires an environment to run correctly.

Comment: appreciate the response but as I mentioned in the title of my question "can't find respective python api", so I'm aware `gcloud` won't work and I'm also aware an api would be the next option, I just don't know whether theres a specific api or if I have to build my own using various APIs

Answer (score 1):

An up-to-date and more convenient way could be like below

PS1. I have just run the code and just copied as is

PS2. Default method inputs might ne confusing. eg '{your-project-prefix}-develop', could be `gcp-project-id-develop` or `gcp-project-id-staging` that where you will run the code on.

```html
# pylint: disable=missing-module-docstring,missing-function-docstring,import-outside-toplevel
# pylint: disable=too-many-arguments,unused-argument,no-value-for-parameter
import os
import logging
from typing import List

from google.cloud import storage
from google.cloud.firestore_admin_v1.services.firestore_admin import client as admin_client
from google.cloud.firestore_admin_v1.types import firestore_admin

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def create_storage_bucket_if_not_exists(
    gcp_project_id: str = '{your-project-prefix}-develop',
    bucket_name: str = '{your-project-prefix}-backup-firestore-develop'
):
    storage_client = storage.Client(project=gcp_project_id)
    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    if not bucket.exists():
        bucket.storage_class = 'STANDARD'
        storage_client.create_bucket(bucket, location='us')


def get_client(
    service_account: str = '{your-service-account-path}'
):
    os.environ.unsetenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS')
    os.environ.pop('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS', None)
    os.environ.setdefault('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS', service_account)

    firestore_admin_client = admin_client.FirestoreAdminClient()
    return firestore_admin_client


def get_database_name(
    client: admin_client.FirestoreAdminClient,
    gcp_project_id: str = '{your-project-prefix}-develop'
):
    return client.database_path(gcp_project_id, '(default)')


def export_documents(
    client: admin_client.FirestoreAdminClient,
    database_name: str,
    collections: List[str] = None,
    bucket_name: str = '{your-project-prefix}-backup-firestore-develop',
    gcp_project_id: str = '{your-project-prefix}-develop'
):
    if collections is None:
        collections = []

    bucket = f'gs://{bucket_name}'
    request = firestore_admin.ExportDocumentsRequest(
        name=database_name,
        collection_ids=collections,
        output_uri_prefix=bucket
    )

    # it is gonna be finalized in the background - async
    operation = client.export_documents(
        request=request
    )
    return operation


def backup():
    client = get_client()
    database_name = get_database_name(client)
    create_storage_bucket_if_not_exists()
    export_documents(client, database_name, [])
    logger.info('Backup operation has been started!')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
    backup()
```

And here you can see the backup directories under GCS bucket
[image]